# ComboBox load the Worksheet names into Dropdown List

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I cannot seem to get a combobox to work. I'm trying to add a dropdown combobox that displays all worksheets in my workbook.
My first step was to create a combobox which adds the sheets but the box does not add any sheetnames

Here is my code:

```
Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim WS As Worksheet
For Each WS In Worksheets
ComboBox1.AddItem (WS.Name)
Next WS


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you add items through the Event 'Change'. If there is no change in the combobox (because there aren't any items) this event never fires.

Instead you can add your code to the Initialize or Activate Event of your Form. For example:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    For Each WS In Worksheets
        ComboBox1.AddItem (WS.Name)
    Next WS
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will proper result

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()   
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Main" Then
    Me.ComboBoxpgname.AddItem ws.Name
    End If
    Next ws    
End Sub
```